# MaxPooledStatements setting in JDBC oracle

Tags: oracle, jdbc

I can't figure out how to set MaxPooledStatements in Oracle using the Oracle thin JDBC driver.  Could someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
Properties p = new Properties();
p.setProperty("user", userid);
p.setProperty("password", password);
p.setProperty("MaxPooledStatements", "200");
// set other properties 
Connection conn = driver.connect(url, p);  // can also use DriverManager but no real benefit
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you read more about statement pooling with Oracle. For instance [here](http://www.oracle.com/technology/pub/articles/vasiliev-oracle-jdbc.html)

> Although Oracle JDBC drivers are
>   designed with the supposition that
>   implicit caching is enabled, this
>   feature is not turned on by default.
>   To enable implicit caching on the
>   connection, you can set the
>   implicitCachingEnabled property of the
>   corresponding OracleConnection object
>   to true and set the statementCacheSize
>   property to a positive integer. This
>   can be done as follows:

```
  conn.setImplicitCachingEnabled(true);
  conn.setStatementCacheSize(10);
```

> When using aUCP JDBC connection pool, you can enable statement caching
>   by setting maxStatements property to a positive integer:

```
  pds.setMaxStatements(10);
```